# What local storage is best for android list

Tags: android, storage

I have a list of Shapes--Triangle, Square, Rectangle, Pentagram.  These shapes were input via a text field and recalled to display the text later on cue.  There will probably be around 200 entries.

How exactly is this done?  I have seen that there are a lot of ways, but I couldn't tell by the descriptions which one is best?

Comment: Does the storage need to be persistent? By that I mean, do you need the list saved between different usages of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up at ArrayList. It works like a Vector. A great way to store your data. 
If you want to store it to a database, you can do it via SQLite, a built in database in Android.

Comment: If I had to edit and retrieve the data to change it, would a database be better?  And delete it?  Maybe I should have said that part...

Comment: Yes, you can do something like this:

Your data will be stored in the database. When your program runs, you can retrieve all the data, displays them on the arraylist. when you do updates, all the information will be updated on the database. So the next time you run your programs the updated data will be there. Database is probably a good way of keeping your data up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a max size or know exactly how many shapes there are, you should use a Shape[].
If you don't know how many shapes you will need to store, you should use a List.

Use sqllite if you want this list of items to be saved when you quit the app, and loaded again when the user restarts.  Don't use sqllite constantly, generally you want to load from you database when starting, and write to the database when closing.

Comment: I need the info to be saved between each time the program is opened.  Why should I not use SQLlite for all my database needs?  Do Lists survive the program being turned off?

Comment: no, Lists and Arrays will both be cleared from memory when the app is removed.  You have to write to disk if you want data to survive the program being turned off.  SQLLite is probably the fastest and best way to write to disk.  You don't want to write all the time because reading and writing to the database takes a lot longer than reading/writing to memory.  You want the user to do everything they need in memory, and then save what is in memory to the disk.

Comment: So when the program starts, I create Lists for all the corresponding entries in the table, alter the lists, and then when the program shuts down, store everything in the table?  That may be a lot of stuff to move in and out of the table.

Answer (score 0):

static final ArrayList> arraylistobject = new ArrayList>();

private void yourFunctionName()

{

```
HashMap<String,Object> temp = new HashMap<String,Object>();




    temp.put("imageUri", drawableID);




    temp.put("key",String);




    arraylistobject.add(temp);




    HashMap<String,Object> temp1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();




    temp1.put("imageUri",  drawableID);




    temp1.put("key",String);




    arraylistobject.add(temp1);
```

}

you can use the above define arraylist with hashmap and then you can add all shapes of list inti local storage .